# How can I add more than 1 row for a row in Data Step of SAS

Tags: sas

Let us say, I have a table like this.

```
# ID, X, Y
1, 0, 1
2, 1, 0
3, 1, 1
```

My resulting output should look like this

```
# ID, X, Y, R
1, 0, 1, Y
2, 1, 0, X
3, 1, 1, X
3, 1, 1, Y
```

So, you can see that for ID 3, we now have two rows instead of one, as both X and Y are one there, and the R column should have an entry for all columns with value 1.

So, my question is, how can this kind of flattening be done with the Data Step of SAS? Note here that in my case, both X and Y cannot be zero. At least one of them would be 1.

Comment: Do you want to also keep track of IDs that do not get flattened because both X and Y are zero ?

Comment: @Richard Both X and Y cannot be zero in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `OUTPUT` statement as part of a `IF THEN` do block clause.

```
  if x = 1 then do;
    r = 'x';
    output;
  end;
  if y = 1 then do;
    r = 'y';
    output;
  end;
```

If you have many variables that need to be Arrrrrified use a variable `ARRAY`

```
  array myRvars x y z p q r s t u z1-z10;
  do index = 1 to dim(myRvars);
    if myRvars(index) = 1 then do;
      r = vname(myRvars(index));
      output;
    end;
  end;
```